# Prove that $|\tanh y - \tanh x | \leq|y-x|$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can i prove that $|\tanh y - \tanh x |\leq |y-x|$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R} $?

I try with that

$$\left|\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} - \frac{e^{y}-e^{-y}}{e^{y}+e^{-y}} \right| \leq |y-x|$$

But I don't know what should I do next. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem?

Comment: If you may use calculus, you can just argue that $\|\tanh'\|\leq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* The derivative of $\tanh(x)$ is $\dfrac{1}{(\cosh (x))^2}$ and $\cosh (x)\ge1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.